StepFunction to Lambda to EKS
I have a requirement to run the EKS job to perform certain task. The flow is like this, StepFunction has 3 stages (stage1, stage2, stage3). Each stage has specific task to do and has an docker image that is available in AWS ECR. Stage1 should trigger EKS job so that pods get created and this image1 gets executed. Then it will move on to Stage2 and so on.
Since, the StepFunction can't directly communicate with EKS private endpoint, I want to introduce lambda.
I'm looking for cloudformation script. Can someone help me in getting this flow executed?

Workflow of Step Functions:

Invokes AWS Lambda functions within every stage.
The first Lambda function initiates an EKS job in Stage 1.

Triggers EKS Job:

There is a Lambda function that communicates with EKS( using the AWS SDK for Kubernetes).

CloudFormation Template:

EKS Cluster provisioning (or assumed to already exist).
IAM Roles and Policies for Lambda functions.
Definition of Step Functions workflow.
Lambda functions for every stage.
CF template code below, I had similar requirement in past and tried to pick up in pieces from the same. Please let me know if this works, may be you need some modification or fixes in this according to your resources.

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  
  # IAM Role for Step Function Execution
  StepFunctionExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - states.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: StepFunctionPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:InvokeFunction
                Resource: "*"

  # IAM Role for Lambda Functions
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: LambdaExecutionPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - eks:DescribeCluster
                  - eks:ListClusters
                  - eks:DescribeUpdate
                  - eks:CreateFargateProfile
                  - eks:CreateNodegroup
                  - eks:DeleteNodegroup
                  - eks:DeleteFargateProfile
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: "*"

  # Lambda Function for Stage1 (EKS Job Trigger)
  Stage1Lambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs16x
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          var aws=Require("aws-sdk");Function `Handlern!


